# Batch file: Reading registry keys and finding user input exists or not

Tags: batch-file, registry

I am writing a batch file to accept user given string value and need to query the HKLM registry to find whether user given string/key exists or not.

1. For instance, I need to look at below registry

   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs
2. On my machine, it has got 3 entries beneath the "Microsoft SDKs" viz, 
   .NETFramework
   Slverlight
   Windows
3. If user provides "BlahBlah", I should check the content/list of strings at step 2 and if exists do-something else do-some-other-thing

Can anyone suggest me how to get this please? Please let me know if further explanation is needed.

Regards,
Kumar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off

set /p search_for=what you want to check?

reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs" 2>nul|findstr /i /e "%search_for%" 1>nul 2>nul && (
  echo %search_for% does  exist
  rem color will set errorlevel to 0 to prevent the negative execution
  color
) || (
  echo %search_for% does NOT exist
)
```

Have on mind that Windows XP HE  does not have `REG` command

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Its almost serving my purpose but when I provide string which doesn't exists for 5 times and then enter a valid string, it displays {"VALID_STRING" does exists} 5 times.

Im not sure what went wrong. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to use PowerShell for that. Here is an example: [Working with Registry Entries](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315394.aspx)